# Swift make user selection on picker view the title for a button

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, uipickerview, xcode9

So, I'm not sure if I've been staring at my code so long I've become dumb or if this is a bit too advanced for my current skills. I am trying to make a pickerview pop up when the user presses a button using [DPPickerManager](https://github.com/priore/DPPickerManager) and when the user selects a color the title of the button is supposed to change to what was selected by the user. Flowing the directions I was able to link the button and pickerview but I can't get the button title to change. Here's my code:

```
    @IBAction func colorPicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let condition = ["Blue", "Black", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"]
    DPPickerManager.shared.showPicker(title: "Strings Picker", selected: "Value 1", strings: condition) { (value, ind, cancel) in
        if !cancel {
            //sender.titleLabel.text = value![index].text
            print(value as Any)
        }

    }
}
```

I keep getting this error: Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()' and I think its because of the value's index but I am unsure. Can someone please help me?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code and it's working fine for me.

```
@IBAction func btnActionTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let condition = ["Blue", "Black", "Green", "Orange", "Purple"]

    DPPickerManager.shared.showPicker(title: "String Picker", selected: "Value 1", strings: condition) { (value, index, cancel) in
        if !cancel {
            if let value = value {
                sender.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
                print(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just changed following code to get value instead of optional value.

```
if let value = value {
    print(value)
}
```

I’m getting string value there and print fine in console.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Could you explain your answer a bit more so I don't run into this issue in the future?

Comment: Yes, First of value is returning string in completion block of showPicker method. Your are going to access via array so it's not way to access value. Another thing is string returning optional value which mean value can be nil. So I have getting value by using if let value = value condition. This means if value is nil then code inside if block never execute otherwise print your value.

Comment: Would it be possible to make sure value is never nil?

Comment: Yes, Currently in your code there are all values are not nil in array...

Comment: Right, I meant is there a way to hardcode it? Like if in the future I wanted to do something similar to this but the user enters variables that can later be selected from a pickerview.

Comment: @yukimoda, Yes, but there should be nil value. then you must need to check for that.